# Не отображается сайт на битриксе! 500 ошибка

Tags: битрикс

Привет всем!
У меня такая проблема: не отображается сайт на битриксе полностью, в окне браузера никаких ошибок, просто белый экран, когда открываю показать код страницы - там пусто, в админку вхожу  - там весь код есть, админка работает... Подскажите, что это вообще может быть. ((( Сайт phiolent.com

Comment: 500 - это ошибка сервера.
Сайт с самого начала не отображался или вы что-то сделали перед появлением ошибки? Хотелось бы знать ваши последние действия.

Comment: Сайт отображался, вчера правила структуру. . .ничего не писала просто отступы в самом документе ставила, после этого белый экран и просмотр кода страницы пуст

Comment: Где-то лишний отступ поставила. Удаляй теперь.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь. Надеюсь, получится.

Comment: @Phiolent, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Ошибка 500 может быть вызвана ошибкой в коде сайта (но это не единственная причина ее возникновения). Вам нужно прежде всего попробовать заглянуть в логи сервера, чтобы узнать, нет ли ошибки в коде, и если есть, то в каком файле или строке. Можно также попробовать разрешить вывод подробной информации об ошибках в файле .htaccess (если у вас отображается белый экран, то наверняка такой вывод запрещен). А еще можно попробовать просто перезагрузить сервер (если ваш хостинг это позволяет), т.к. бывает и такое, что произошел, например, сбой в базе данных (это обычно и лечится простой перезагрузкой).

Comment: хмм разрешила вывод ошибок в файл. . . теперь не могу вообще зайти на сайт. . даже в админку. . подскажите еще какой-то способ устранения этой ошибки

Comment: Теперь при входе в админку тоже белый экран?

Comment: Нет, 500 ошибка Internal Server Error, все же .htaccess  сработал (но не так, как нужно было).  (

Comment: А в файле ошибок что?

Comment: В битриксе перерыла все папки, не нашла лог, скорее всего он на сервере хоста лежит, завтра уже посмотрю, написала в саппорт хоста, думаю, смогут последнюю рабочую версию мне поднять.

Comment: Через битрикс вы логи ошибок не найдете, php не имеет доступа выше папки сайта, а логи почти всегда находятся именно там.